# crystal report paging issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am using visual studio development tool for crystal report. In the report, I am not able to go on 3rd page, that is, in the report viewer paging works till page 2, then when I try to go on next page it reloads the 2nd page only. What is the problem here? It has 15 pages and I can view the last page, i.e. page 15.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is a third page? (I'm being serious, not sarcastic)

With Crystal, the viewer component either works or it doesn't. If it's loads the report, I can't think of any reason it would get "lost". I've worked with Crystal in a lot of environments, and I've never seen what you're describing. If it can't go to another page, it's probably processed every record.

Comment: it shows total pages..as 1/15 then i go on 2nd page..but after that i does not let me load the 3rd page..if i go to last page..i shows me last (in tis case 15) but not the page after 2nd

Comment: it redirects to 2nd page only...when i click on next page it process the data bt i guess it reloads the second page only...kindly help me with the same

Comment: Do you have a sub-report being called on the the 3rd page? You might try removing subreports, conditional formulas, tables one-at-a-time until it pages correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a page lifecycle issue.  Bind your report source before page_load, e.g. OnInitComplete.

Answer (score 1):

you can Put Report Source in Page_Init instead of Page_Load
 And 
report parameters Page_Load 
I think it works Probably